# insert record when datetime = system time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to sql so bear with me. I want to insert a record into another table when a datetime column = the system time. I know this is an infinite loop. I am not sure any other way to handle what I am trying to solve.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Que
(Name, Time)
SELECT ProspectName, ProspectDate
FROM myProspects where ProspectDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I need to place a phone call at a certain time. I need to insert the record into another table to execute the call when the time = now. If you have a better way of handling this, please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and what the desired result is (be explicit)

Comment: something like that, but I need it to constantly loop through the records and do nothing when there are no records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql server, you can use the getdate() function.

You would need to insert the createdate into a column of the call on insert, also using getdate() or if using .net System.Datetime.Now

e.g. select all calls that happened in the last x amount of time in SQL server:

select * from calls where createdate > getdate() - .1

Comment: I don't know if that would work, the calls have to be made at the time that is in the time column. An interval would work, I am not sure how to implement that.

Comment: I was assuming the createdate column would be of type datetime. Therefore you can do something like select * from calls where createdate > getdate() - .001 and it will be reading records created in the last couple of seconds or however long you want the time interval to be.

Comment: how do i loop through all the records constantly? Thank you

Comment: You would need to set up a process that runs at certain times. An example is to create a task through task scheduler that is scheduled to run a C# windows console application (exe) every hour that runs your application that contains the SQL calls.

Comment: I can use sql command to do that, but I am afraid that will not be frequent enough. Is an infinite loop that inserts the records good practice? I just want to make sure calls are being made based on the reminder call time.

Comment: You could use a SSIS package forloop container if you want to keep it in SQL.

Comment: I can see that the task schedule will allow tasks to be run every 5 min indefinetly, that will work. Thank you!